# Как ввести текст в определённую строчку текстового документа в c#

Tags: c#, filewriter

Как вставить текст в .txt документ, но при этом в определённую строчку? В первом случае надо например на 2-ую строку, не заменяя старое. Во втором под строчку с определённым текстом, так же не заменяя старый текст. Вот актуальный код на запись.

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(testforwrite, false, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
writer.WriteLine("Тест")
write.Close();
```

Например, есть текстовый документ и в нём текст:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

Нужно, чтобы текст вставился между строками в 1 случае:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
DDD
ddd
```

А во 2-ом перед определённой строчкой, содержащей bbb

```
aaa
DDD
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

Вот неработающий второй код:

```
string path = "modlist.txt";

string item = "MOD"; // что вставляем

var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();

string target = "+"; // по идеи ищет + в txt файле

int index = lines.FindIndex(s => s == target); 

lines.Insert(index, item); // должен добавить текст MOD перед строкой с "+", но ничего не происходит
```

Comment: Определенную чем? Порядковым номером, содержимым срок, еще каким-то условием? Строчку надо вставить или перезаписать? Новую поверх старой? Дополните пожалуйста вопрос.

Comment: Извините, дополнил.

Comment: [Вот](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-insert-text-at-a-specified-line-of-a-file-using-c-sharp1) что нашел

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: нет, работает неправильно стирает старый текст и в целом непонятно работает.

Comment: Текстовый документ уже имеется? Или файл изначально пустой (отсутствует)? | Приведите желаемый результат именно в виде текста.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov поправил вопрос.

Comment: В представленных текстовых файлах нет знака `+`. Допишите, где он должен быть: отдельной строкой или в составе строки?

Comment: Он есть в отдельной строке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнём с критики.

Вы, когда пишете код, обращайте внимание на подсказки Студии (если, конечно, вы не пишете в Блокноте). И читайте документацию.

Вы написали:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(testforwrite, false, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
```

Первым параметром в конструкторе `StreamWriter` идёт путь (имя файла). Так дайте ему осмысленное название. Например, общепринятые `path` или `filename`.

Второй параметр - append: `false` означает переписать файл. То есть всё предыдущее содержимое будет потеряно. Просто читайте документацию к используемым классам!

Третье. Никогда не используйте кодировку `Default`! На каждом компьютере она своя. В итоге файл, записанный вашей программой на одном компьютере, может не открыться (выдать кракозябры) вашей же программой на другом компьютере.

Укажите какую-либо конкретную кодировку. Если файл предназначен для использования только в вашей программе, то `Encoding.Unicode`, если будет передаваться куда-либо (по сети) для использования в других программах, то `Encoding.UTF8`.

---

Приведу самые простые способы решения ваших задач.

Используем методы класса `File`. Читаем и записываем файл с их помощью.

Считанный массив преобразуем в `List` - этот класс имеет удобный метод `Insert`, выполняющий нужную нам работу.

```
string path = "test.txt";

string item = "DDD"; // что вставляем
        
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();

int index = 3; // после какой строки вставлять
lines.Insert(index, item);

File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
```

Для второй задачи опять же используем метода класса `List`. С его помощью находим индекс строки, перед которой потом сделаем вставку.

```
string target = "bbb";
int index = lines.FindIndex(s => s == target);
lines.Insert(index, item);
```

Если текст, который ищем, расположен не на отдельной строке, а содержится в ней, то меняем сравнение:

```
int index = lines.FindIndex(s => s.Contains(target));
```

Comment: А ещё `using` надо...

Comment: спасибо огромное, я и так документацию читаю, просто спутал строчки, когда писал вопрос, у меня так то там true и utf8 кодировка, на счёт названия учту, пойду проверять.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, первый ваш вариант работает отлично, но второй почему-то ничего не записывает. Сейчас дополню вопрос с кодом.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov почему-то еще при первом способе появляются квадратики с вопросами, до строки с моим текстом.

Comment: @Сергей - проблема в кодировках; укажите их явно

Comment: Где их указать?

Comment: У вашего метода есть минус: это то, что он не может работать с большими файлами. Если размер файла достаточно большой, то у вас будет `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: @return - это да, но несколько сотен мегабайт он прожуёт и не подавится. В зависимости от количества оперативки и настроек файла подкачки могут и файлы в несколько десятков гигов нормально отрабатываться. | Но главное то, что судя по уровню вопросов автора, о  таких объёмах речь явно не идёт. Речь пока идёт об азах, о начале обучения языку.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Так ему об этом нужно и сказать. А если ваша прога дошла до файлов подкачки, что это тревожный звоночек (если это не игра какая-нибудь, конечно).

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы что то вставить в текст(изменить его), вы считываете старый текст, меняете его на новый и записываете в файл(перезаписываете - удаляете и создаете с тем же именем)

Comment: Было бы неплохо оформить пример кода, чтобы ответ стал полноценным.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
static readonly string rowSmpl = "xxx" + Environment.NewLine;

static void InsertString(string path, int position, string str, Encoding? encoding = null)
{
    // checks skipped

    encoding ??= Encoding.Default;

    using var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    using var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding);
    using var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, encoding)
    {
        AutoFlush = true
    };
    var tmpPath = Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".tmp";
    using var tmpStream = File.Open(tmpPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    using var tmpReader = new StreamReader(tmpStream, encoding);
    using var tmpWriter = new StreamWriter(tmpStream, encoding, 1024)
    {
        AutoFlush = true
    };

    var rowLen = encoding.GetByteCount(rowSmpl);
    var seekOffs = rowLen * position;
    stream.Seek(seekOffs, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    Span<char> buf = stackalloc char[1024];

    do
    {
        var bufLen = reader.ReadBlock(buf);

        tmpWriter.Write(buf[..bufLen]);
    } while (stream.Position != stream.Length);

    stream.Seek(seekOffs, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    writer.WriteLine(str);

    tmpStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    do
    {
        var bufLen = tmpReader.ReadBlock(buf);

        writer.Write(buf[..bufLen]);
    } while (tmpStream.Position != tmpStream.Length);

    tmpWriter.Close();
    File.Delete(tmpPath);
}
```

---

Как это работает? Нам нужно вставить строку, т. е. нам нужно как-то скопировать данные после места вставки вперёд, а затем вписать строку в это же место вставки. Для этого мы берём и создаём временный `.tmp` файл в который записываем часть после места вставки. Затем записываем нашу строку, а после этого читаем данные из временного файла и записываем их в файл поверх строки. Временный файл удаляем.

Т. к. формат строк такой: 3 любые буквы + новая линия, то мы можем создать сэмпл для строки, а затем вычислять её размер в байтах в зависимости от кодировки. Потом это кол-во байтов множим на позицию вставки и получаем необходимое смещение для вставки.

Comment: Возможно, будет метод с прямой записью данных без временного файла, но я не знаю, как это сделать максимально правильно.

Comment: понял, посмотрю, спасибо